# Why is Laravel Elixir is not minifying my code?

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

I am using laravel elixir to compile and minify my code. But for some reason when I do the **gulp -production** task I am still not getting minified code. I would love to have minified javascript and css code for production.

My gulpfile :

```
'use strict';

process.env.DISABLE_NOTIFIER = false;

var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass([
        './resources/assets/css/**/**/*.scss'
    ], 'public/css/style.css');

    mix.scripts([
       'app.js'
    ], 'public/js/angular/app.js');

    mix.scripts([
       'jquery/chosenSelect.js',
       'jquery/fileUpload.js',
       'jquery/velocity.min.js',
       'jquery/leanModal.js',
       'jquery/sectionScroll.js'
    ], 'public/js/jquery.js');

    mix.scripts([
        'services/OverheatingService.js'
    ], 'public/js/angular/services/services.js');

    mix.scripts([
        'controllers/LoopController.js',
        'controllers/AlertController.js',
        'controllers/LibraryController.js',
        'controllers/StationController.js',
        'controllers/ProfileController.js',
        'controllers/HomeController.js',
        'controllers/MainController.js',
        'controllers/RecordController.js',
        'controllers/SpecificuserController.js',
        'controllers/DeleteAccountController.js',
        'controllers/RegisterController.js',
        'controllers/EditProfileController.js',
        'controllers/SpecificLoopController.js',
        'controllers/SpecificTagController.js'
    ], 'public/js/angular/controllers/controllers.js');

    mix.scripts([
        'directives/tooltip.js',
        'directives/smoothScroll.js'
    ], 'public/js/angular/directives/directives.js');
});

//To watch changes in sass files
elixir.Task.find('sass').watch('./resources/assets/css/**/*.scss');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Command is `gulp --production` **not** `gulp - production`.

You may also have a look at the [Elixir Docs for Running Elixir](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir#running-elixir).

Comment: Do you know why it makes my javascript crash when i do this? (css is fine)

Comment: Or how i can just minify my css and not my javascript

Comment: I dont know your code so i cant say why it crashes. You may have a look at your error console which error is thrown. So far the code above is looking good.

Comment: @JimPeeters You can use ``mix.combine`` on your javascript files, this does not minify the code when you run ``gulp --production``, simply just concatenates. I think if you use ``combine`` the paths are relative to your gulpfile whereas ``scripts`` and ``styles`` are relative to output folder.